# Creating a JavaScript array-like object that can be used like an array and an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, defineproperty

Is it possible to create an object that can be used like an array and an object?

The closest I have gotten so far is below which just allows you to assign a value using either an array key or object property:

```js
var ALO = {
  db: {}
};
Object.defineProperty(ALO, 'length', {
  get: function() {
    var count = 0;
    for (var prop in ALO.db) {
      if (ALO.db.hasOwnProperty(prop)) count++;
    }
    return count;
  },
  enumerable: false
});

function add(baseObj, obj) {
  for (var prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      if (!isNaN(prop)) {
        //create a default string begining with i
        baseObj.db["i" + prop] = obj[prop];
      } else {
        baseObj.db[prop] = obj[prop];
      }

      Object.defineProperty(baseObj, prop, {
        get: function() {
          return baseObj.db[prop];
        },
        set: function(newValue) {
          baseObj.db[prop] = newValue;
        },
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: true
      });

      Object.defineProperty(baseObj, baseObj.length - 1, {
        get: function() {
          return baseObj.db[prop];
        },
        set: function(newValue) {
          baseObj.db[prop] = newValue;
        },
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: true
      });
    }
  }
}

add(ALO, {
  "myprop": "myvalue"
});
document.write(ALO["myprop"] + "<br>");
ALO[0] = "mynewvalue";
document.write(ALO["myprop"] + "<br>");
ALO["myprop"] = "mynewervalue";
document.write(ALO["myprop"]);
```

I would like to be able to automatically create what is needed when assigning a non existing item e.g.

```
ALO[1] = "create and assign this string";
```

or

```
ALO["somenonexistingprop"] = "another string";
```

Comment: http://www.nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/06/advanced-javascript-objects-arrays-and-array-like-objects/

Comment: http://2ality.com/2013/05/quirk-array-like-objects.html

Comment: What behaviour are you trying to get which is different from a normal JS object, i.e. `var a = {}`?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the links but what I am after is a way to use this array-like object exactly like an array and exactly like an object. I want all the methods that are available for an array and I want to use them in the same way as you would natively.

Comment: @Ryan1729 I want be to able to access (set and get) the data using it's ordered key or by it's property. Basically I would like this array-like object to be indistinguishable from an array and indistinguishable from an object. So you can use it in place with existing code and it would just work.

Comment: Do you also need to be able to use methods like `ALO.indexOf()`? I think the only way to get all array methods automatically is by inheriting from `Array.prototype`.

Comment: @Barmar yes all array methods. I thought with Object.defineProperty something like this might be possible.

Comment: Even built-in array-like objects, like `NodeList`, don't inherit all the array methods. That's why you have to write things like `Array.prototype.forEach.call(nodelist, function(...){})`

Comment: I'm confused. Arrays already are "indistinguishable from objects", because they **are** objects. Can you give some sample code that shows what you are trying to do that you couldn't do with a plain old array?

Comment: That's right. You can do `myArray = [1, 2, 3];` and then `myArray.someName = "foo";`

Comment: @Barmar Yes but I would then want to be able to get "foo" using myArray[4] as well as myArray['someName']

Comment: @Craig: Use `Object.defineProperty` on the array? You can't intercept `somenonexistingprop` without an ES6 proxy, though, and proxies are horrible. (Well, this is already horrible.)

Comment: So you want `a.prop = "foo"` to sort of work like `push`? Why would you want to do that? What's the use case?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will find that normal `Arrays` in Javascript inherit from `Object`, which means you can abuse them like normal objects if you want.

```js
let MyArray = [1, 2, 3];
console.log('let MyArray = [1, 2, 3];');

console.log('Typeof MyArray = ', typeof(MyArray));

console.log('Wait.....');

console.log('So can I just assign stuff to an array like an object?');

MyArray['key'] = 'value';
console.log(`MyArray.key = 'value';`);
console.log('console.log(MyArray.key) =>', JSON.stringify(MyArray.key));

console.log('Keys:', JSON.stringify(Object.keys(MyArray)));
console.log('Array Length:', MyArray.length);

console.log('TADA, the standard browser Array does what you want');
```

There are probably reasons not to do this other than it being very confusing, but I believe it would fulfill your requirements, and requires no code!

**EDIT:** After reading some of the comments below the fold, it seems the OP for some reason wants to access properties added in `Object` mode as array members. If you need that, you can just use `Object.keys(MyArray)` instead of `MyArray` as demonstrated in the last lines of the console output above.

Comment: @Craig, does this fit your use-case? if not, please tell me what it doesn't do.

Comment: Not really. I would want to access the same value using the index(0,1,2,3 etc) or the key('key','first_name','age' etc). So for your example of MyArray['key'] which returns "value" I would also want to be able to use MyArray[3] and get "value". And if I set a new value using either 'key' or 3 i would want it to update both. I would also want length to return the number of values where 'key' and 3 are counted as 1 (the same thing)